# How to convert into CSV with header and body from query result: codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I'm trying to build a csv conversion for my project.

The code is done but, it only returns the header.

Here is the code in controller:

```
public function convcsv(){

        $list = $this->searchResult;
        $headerArray = array("Foreign Key", "Name", "Email", "Category");

        $header = str_replace(",", "", $headerArray);
        $datas = implode(',', $header) . "\r\n";

        foreach($list as $body)
        {
            $body = str_replace(",", "", $body);
            $datas.= implode(',', $body) . "\r\n";
        }

        $datas = mb_convert_encoding($datas, "SJIS-win", "UTF-8");

        $csvFileName = "phpList_" . date('Ymd_His') . ".csv";
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $csvFileName);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        while (ob_get_level() > 0)
        {
            ob_end_clean();
        }

        ob_start();
        print trim($datas);
        ob_flush();
        ob_end_clean();
        exit;
    }
```

`$list = $this->searchResult` in the controller is:

```
$this->searchResult = $this->user_model->get_users($searchKey, $config["per_page"], $page);
```

How can I possibly get the body?